# Changing to a directory found somewhere in the tree hierarchy

Tags: linux, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I frequently find myself typing:

```
cd a/directory/I/use/a/lot
```

and inside that directory there are a lot of folders I `cd` to back and forth.

Is there a `oh-my-zsh` plugin that allows to type like:

```
cd somd<TAB>
```

And then autocompletes with a list of directories whose name contains the string `somed`, and that are **reachable** from the current directory? For instance given the directory structure

```
somedirX
foo/bar/somedirY
baz/somedirZ/bum
```

Typing `cd somed<TAB>` should return this completion list

```
somedirX
somedirY
somedirZ
```

I could not find anything yet.

Comment: No, the list should be `somedirX foo/bar/somedirY baz/somedirZ` otherwise `cd` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define a function for the completion like that:

```
_children_dirs() {
    find . -type d -name "${words[CURRENT]}*" -printf "%P\n" \
        | while read -r line; do
      compadd -U -X "Subdirectories: " "$line"
    done
    compstate[insert]=menu # no expand
}
```

This function can now be used as a completer for `cd` with:

```
compdef _children_dirs cd
```

However, I do not think it is a good idea to use the last command. Indeed, try to do that from your home directory and you will freeze your shell for a while (*Ctrl+c* to stop). A better solution could be to assign a key sequence to this completion and use it only when it is needed and safe:

```
zstyle ':completion:children-dirs:*' completer _children_dirs
zle -C children-dirs menu-complete _generic
bindkey '^Y' children-dirs
```

With that, **Ctrl+y** will trigger *children_dirs* completion.

There is another solution that I think is better, if you are ready to use another command.

```
function ccd { cd $1 }
compdef _children_dirs ccd
```

This block defines a new command *ccd* that uses _\children_dirs_ as completer (so triggered with TAB).

You can personalize the name filter in *find* to search for the pattern anywhere in the filename with: `"*${words[CURRENT]}*"`.

Edit: I have created a [plugin](https://github.com/rools32/children-dirs) for zsh with that.